# 404 error in django when visiting / Runserver returns no errors though

Tags: python, django, get, http-status-code-404, django-urls

When I syncdb and runserver everything works correctly in Django, but when I try to visit the webpage that it is on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`  it returns a 404 error.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in MyBlog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

The strange part is that when I visit `/admin` on the page it works fine. I dont understand what is failing here. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Could you show your `urlpatterns` definition?

Comment: And the full traceback while you're at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an URL route to the homepage. The urlpatterns variable in MyBlog.urls should have a tuple pair like (r'^$', app.views.show_homepage), where show_homepage is a function defined in views.py. For more info about the URL dispatcher, you can read about it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [chapter 3 of Django's Writing your first Django app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial03/#design-your-urls) tutorial.

In short, you need to specify (in `urls.py`) which code Django should run for particular URLs; there are no default URLs defined (you'll see a line including the admin URLs in `urls.py`).

Edit your `urls.py` so it looks something like

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="home.html"),
)
```

(you'll also need to create `home.html` in one of the directories specified in `TEMPLATE_DIRS`)