# Newbie. Django Tutorial (from django website) stuck at part 2 - admin

Tags: django, admin

I have read many answers here but none did answer my exact question.

I did the part one, the polls. I started part 2, the admin, however, after runserve, when i try to acces the page, here is the error i get (my project name is john):

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in john.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. ``
```

My code - urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'newgrid.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^newgrid/', include('newgrid.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice
```

settings.py:

```
# Django settings for newgrid project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'C:/john/john/johny.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'cl8%_lzxbct-^ebmpje25%r&amp;5*0=$qmv9gw6i$^arox*kr4$_e'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'newgrid.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'newgrid.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    #'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'polls'
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Thats about it. Oh yea, im in WinXP.

Comment: Did you remember to restart it?

Comment: good question. If you are referring to: "manage.py runserver", then yes. i did CTRL-C and ran the command again. Same result.

Comment: Read the tutorial carefully. You won't be able to access `/` (the index page) until Part 3 of the tutorial. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832178/404-error-in-django-when-visiting-runserver-returns-no-errors-though/11832382#11832382

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're navigating to the wrong URL. As [the tutorial says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial02/#start-the-development-server),

> Now, open a Web browser and go to `/admin/` on your local domain — *e.g.*, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`. You should see the admin's login screen:

Answer (score 3):

In your URLconf, you haven't defined a view for the root URL, that's why your application will only work if you point your browser to a URL starting with `admin/`

Uncomment the following line:

```
# url(r'^$', 'newgrid.views.home', name='home'),
```

and change `'newgrid.views.home'` to an existing view, maybe something that renders a plain template containing some temporary links to play with.

Comment: thanks both, supervacuo and dschulz. both of you are right. It was my bad, the tutorial clearly says to point to /admin. I somehow missed that part. My bad. Also thanks for the code for solution.

Answer (score 2):

I know this was asked a long time ago but perhaps people are still looking here for an answer to the same issue, as I was. For me, the problem that I made was *which* urls.py I had changed. the key is the change the PROJECT urls.py, not the APP urls.py file.

for example, if your PROJECT is called "mysite" and the APP is "polls" the file you want to change is located here:

```
/mysite/urls.py
```

NOT the app version (located in /polls/urls.py).

also, you may have mad the error I did which was to change /polls/urls.py to the new "namespace" syntax and then, after making that change to the /mysite/urls.py, forgetting to change /polls/urls.py back to the original code given in the "Writing more views" section of tutorial 3 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial03/)

hope this helps someone. (it would be my first time contributig to StackOverflow!)

Answer (score 1):

I worked through this tutorial also, and had a problem during part 3 which returned the same error; my confusion was with the directory structure.

I had written the urls.py file in the directory I thought the tutorial specified, but it was `~/mysite/urls.py` whilst the tutorial had actually specified `~/mysite/mysite/urls.py`

The file `~mysite/polls/urls.py`, which the tutorial also prompts us to create, was located correctly, and I should've been suspicious that both sets of instructions only listed the inner directory (`polls` or `mysite`). I had to re-read part 1 of the tutorial after having this problem, but then I finally understood the following text from it:

> The inner `mysite/` directory is the actual Python package for your project.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this Statement "url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),"  under urlpatterns class in "mysite/mysite/urls.py" file,then u can see what u desire

Answer (score 0):

I has the same problem and now got the solution in two ways , by editing the urls.py in **[mysite/mysite/urls.py]** OR change the **ROOT_URLCONF** in the settings to **urls.py** if you already edit the urls.py in the path where manage.py exists.