# Django, blog app, on local server can only see administrator page

Tags: python, django, blogs

Since updating to Django 1.6.5 the simple example of creating a blog in Django does not work correctly for me anymore. After i first create the Django project i can go 127.0.0.1:8000/ and Django is running ok. However once i go a couple steps further and create the Blog App as soon as i add 'blog' to INSTALLED_APPS in the settings.py file I can no longer go to 127.0.0.1:8000   and i can also not go to 127.0.0.1:8000/blog, here is the Page not found(404) error i get at 127.0.0.1:8000/blog:

```
    Request Method:     GET
       Request URL:     http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog

       Using the URLconf defined in mysite2.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

       ^blog/
       ^admin/

       The current URL, blog, didn't match any of these.
```

but i did create the blog address, it's even in the error above, ^blog/
ok I will show you the html and py files i think will be most helpful in identifying my problem.

settings.py file in C:\mysite2\mysite2

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '=ja7o^#pm2hd!swt67%1h!)!et(i$91v1flks9ms-&8@r17((5'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'blog',         ## ***add for blog app
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite2.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite2.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

modles.py file in C:\mysite2\mysite

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

urs.py file in C:\mysite2\mysite2

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite2.views.home', name='home'),   ## ** i tried uncommenting but no help
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),  ## once i add this on i can not go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

admin.py file in C:\mysite2\blog

```
from django.contrib import admin
# Register your models here.
from  blog.models import Post
admin.site.register(Post)
```

urls.py file in C:\mysite2\blog

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from blog.models import Post

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                        #url(r'^$', app.views.show_homepage),  ##http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832178/404-error-in-django-when-visiting-runserver-returns-no-errors-though/11832382#11832382


                        url('r^$', ListView.as_view(
                            queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:10],
                            template_name="blog.html")),

)
```

base.html file in C:\mysite2\blog\templates

```
<h1>Django Tutorial Blog</h1>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

blog.htmls file in C:\mysite2\blog\templates

```
{% extends "base.html" %}    <!-- think a way to mesh in html and python django (this is sytax to do it   {%  %} -->
{% block content %}

{% for post in object_list %}
<h3>{{post.title}}</h3>

<div class = "post_meta">
    on {{ post.date }}
</div>

<div class = "post_body">
    {{ post.body|safe|linebreaks}}  <!-- if linebreaks automaticaly will read it-->
</div>

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

BTW i even though i can not go to 127.0.0:8000/blog or 127.0.0:8000, i can go to 127.0.0:8000\admin  and log in and update blog etc..
If anyone can tell me what the issue is it would make this an amazing day, because i have been going at this question for a while.

thanks, tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
                    url('r^$', ListView.as_view(
```

The `r` should be in front of the `'`. Change the line to this:

```
                    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(
```

Comment: if i append /   to the end of my address i still get the same:
Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/

Using the URLconf defined in mysite2.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^blog/ r^$
    ^admin/

The current URL, blog/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: when i copy and paste it to you it does not show but, it shows on my screen when i initially type it. I am going to http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/    (there is a slash on the very end, why would this not show up to the screen, when i type it is there, but does not show in the stackoverflow site after save edits??)

Comment: so maybe the issue is something to do with my computer not able to register the / at the end of text?

Comment: @user1087809 Please recheck my new answer.